# Get Account Name / Email from Google Drive Android API

Tags: android, google-sheets-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using the new [Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) and I can connect, and do [all that it will allow me to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518044/create-or-open-native-google-documents-using-googledriveapi), but in order to use the SpreadsheetService, I need to extract the accountName/email from the signed in user.

How do I do that?

Here's the code where I connect the Google Drive API. It works fine.

```
private void connect() {

    if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // And, connect!

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            writeLog("Connecting...");
        }

    }
}
```

Here's where I'm using the SpreadsheetService API, **but I need the account name to get the token**.

```
String accountName = "???"; // how do I get this From GoogleClientApi / mGoogleApiClient ?
String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(GDriveActivity.this, accountName, scope, null);
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("v1");
```

I have tried this adding this:

```
String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

... in the `onConnected` method, but it throws a `NullPointerException`.

Also, here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Comment: please give it a reading  https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've now reverted to the below which allows me to get the account at any time.

When I asked this question I was under the impression that I could only get it when initially connecting. Obviously I was incorrect.

```
private String getAccountName() {

    String accountName = null;

    AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
    for (Account account : list) {
        if (account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")) {
            accountName = account.name;
            break;
        }
    }
    return accountName;
}
```

Of course, including the following permission in the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: What if you have multiple google accounts? Then you just automatticaly select the first one.

Comment: I agree with Roel, what if you have multiple accounts? This is the only topic I found for the very same problem I'm facing. I need the Google Drive logged user's email. Do we have a real solution already?

Comment: @LucasEduardo did you find aby solution?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm now using Google EasyPermissions. This give a popup to the user to select which account they want to use.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android

Comment: Ohh I'm using pop up to ask the user which account he wants to select, as LimaNightHawk said above.

Answer (score 14):

You need to add:

```
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
```

when building the client. Then this will work in `onConnected(Bundle)`:

```
String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

assuming you already have the correct permission (which you do):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Is it possible without the Plus API?
Only using com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity?

Comment: Plus is deprecated now.